# Contraction Hierarchy Java Implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, shortest-path

I want to implement Contraction Hierarchy (CH) shortest path in JAVA. So for reference I want some already implemented java version of this algorithm or a step by step algorithm pseudo code. So can you please give me any such reference so that I can implement it?

Comment: https://github.com/RoutingKit/RoutingKit/blob/master/doc/ContractionHierarchy.md This is a C++ implementation of CH.

Answer (score 6):

Well actually I know 2 projects implementing this algorithm one is written in Java and it is [GraphHopper](http://graphhopper.com/)

Then other one is [OSRM](http://project-osrm.org/)  and it's in C++

Answer (score 1):

a good reference is [here](http://i11www.iti.uni-karlsruhe.de/_media/teaching/theses/studienarbeittobiascolumbus.pdf). start implementation now...!

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/vol4/p69-rice.pdf) paper. It has pseudo code for the algorithm and some excellent background.